# io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The steps are undefined

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng, serenity-bdd

I want to run some steps using Cucumber but I receive the following errors:
`io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step 'I launch chrome browse' and 1 other step(s) are undefined. You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:`

The TestRunner.class is

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/Features", // Path to the directory containing your feature files
        glue = "StepDefinitions", // Package name where your step definitions are located
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"} // Specify the desired reporting format
)
public class PostRunner {
    // This class will be empty
    // Cucumber will scan the features and step definitions based on the options provided above
    // The tests will be executed based on the defined scenarios in the feature files
}
```

Project Structure is:

```
src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   |   \---PageObjectModel
|   |   |           HomePage.java
|   |   |           LoginPage.java
|   |   |           OnboardingPage.java
|   |   |           PopupNotificationPage.java
|   |   |           
|   |   \---resources
|   |           chromedriver.exe
|   |           
|   \---test
|       +---java
|       |   +---Features
|       |   |       Logo.feature
|       |   |       SignIn.feature
|       |   |       
|       |   +---runner
|       |   |       PostRunner.java
|       |   |       
|       |   \---StepDefinitions
|       |           Stepdefs.java
|       |           
|       \---resources
```

I tried:

- absolute/ relative path for the featre and glue
- to change the folder from test to main

The errors are:
`io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step 'I launch chrome browse' and 1 other step(s) are undefined. You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:`

or

`io.cucumber.core.feature.GluePath warnWhenWellKnownProjectSourceDirectory WARNING: Consider replacing glue path 'src/test/java/StepDefinitions' with 'StepDefinitions'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario outline you have the text 'I launch chrome browse'.

This text needs to be inside a step definition file inside a *when* annotation.

example:

```
@When("I launch chrome browse")
public void launchChrome() throws Exception {
    ... e.g.: some selenium stuff
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with mentioning full package path along with ***StepDefinitions*** package name?
And please mention class name like below with extending class-> ***AbstractTestNGCucumberTests***:

```
public class TestNGTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work